# What is it, "dying rank"?

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-usage

> I'm buried under a sobbing carpet, and all of a sudden even death and dying rank right down there with plastic flowers on video as a non-event.

Source: Fight Club by Chuck Palahniuk

What is it, "dying rank" ?

Comment: It's not *dying rank* -- it's [*death and dying*] [*rank right down there*]. *Rank* is the verb.

Comment: Even with your help I still struggle to understand the meaning of this sentence. "right down there" - Does it mean, death and dying have a little importance?

Comment: I have no idea; I'd have to read the book up to that point to discover the contextual significance (and for the character the existential significance) of *buried under a sobbing carpet* and *plastic flowers on video*.

Comment: This thing ranks right up there with the wheel as the greatest invention of all time. That thing ranks right down there with shoe umbrellas and the USB pet rock as a dumb invention.

Comment: @ColleenV: I don't know how many USB pet rocks have been sold, but they're on eBay for $19.99 (reduced from $39.98, would you believe!). Apparently the guy who came out with the original (which could perhaps now be marketed as a ***Wi-fi*** pet rock) [became a millionaire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pet_Rock). Not *that* dumb!

Comment: @FumbleFingers Pet rocks are awesome - USB pet rocks are a transparent attempt to sucker people ;)

Answer (score 3):

"Rank" is the verb. "Rank right down there with ... " means "count no more than... ", or "are no more important than... ".

Answer (score 1):

When *things* are "ranked" they are given an order

> rank order

sometimes this can be from most important to least important.

The passage is saying

> death and dying rank ... as a nonevent
>   *death and dying are no longer important (a nonevent)*